# C++ Instantiating a different class from a function in a class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a "Foo.cpp" class and a "Bar.cpp" class. I want to overload the + operator on two arguments of Foo so that adding two Foos returns a Bar with a value that's the product of their values. The code looks like

```
//Foo.h
class Foo
{
public:
    double foo_val;
    Foo();
    Foo(double);
};

Bar* operator+ (Foo&, Foo&)
```

.

```
//Foo.cpp
#include "Foo.h"

Foo::Foo(){foo_val = 0;}
Foo::Foo(double d){foo_val = d;}

Bar* operator+ (Foo& f1, Foo& f2){
    return new Bar(f1.foo_val*f2.foo_val);
}
```

.

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include "Bar.h"
int main(){
    Foo f1 = new Foo(4, 5);
    Foo f2 = new Foo(1, 2);
    Bar = f1+f2;
}
```

Bar is basically identical to Foo at the moment, and it has a constructor "Bar(double);"

It doesn't work at the moment, I think because Bar hasn't been defined before I try to make a new one. (The compiler error is "'Bar' does not name a type") However, I know I can't forward declare Bar at the top because that only works for pointers, whereas I'm trying to construct a new one. Is there some way to get this type of thing to work, or am I going about this totally wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I think defining the operator+ function like this might be better:  Bar operator+(const Foo& f1, const Foo& f2). Otherwise you should keep track of Bar*, and be unable to make something like f1 + f2 + B2. Take a look to this page http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~donnie/cs11/cpp/cpp-ops.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually very simple.  In `Foo.h`, you need to *forward declare* `class Bar`, so that the declaration of `operator+` is valid:

```
class Bar;

class Foo
{
    // ...
};

Bar* operator+ (Foo& f1, Foo& f2);
```

Then, in `Foo.cpp`, you need to `include Bar.h` since here you really need to know how `Bar` is declared:

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include "Bar.h"

// ...

Bar* operator+ (Foo& f1, Foo& f2)
{
    // Now you can use Bar's constructor
    return new Bar(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options.

(1) Put

```
#include "Bar.h"
```

at the beginning of `Foo.h`. But if `Bar.h` already has `#include "Foo.h"`, this will cause a circular dependency, so this is *not* a viable option.

(2) Put

```
class Bar;
```

in `Foo.h`, before the class definition of `Foo`.

Comment: Why is (1) preferred?  You should always prefer forward declarations in header files since it saves compile time.

Comment: Good question. I have no other reason than that is what I've always done. I removed that preference. (But I believe compile time is negligibly different, however, if you ensure the header file is only included once.)

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer Saving compile time is the least important benefit here. Including header inside another creates a dependency between them which is wrong from SW engineering point of view (unless the dependency is real and by design).

Comment: No. @icepack, you will have to include a *definition* for Bar eventually. Anytime you have Foo.h, you *must* have Bar.h. That dependency is real, intentional, and unavoidable.

Comment: In this example this depends on whether `operator+` is always required when `Foo` is used (you can create a Foo without a Bar), but let's not get lost in this discussion and agree that forward declarations are preferrable to includes where possible.

Comment: @PaulDraper Your conclusion is wrong. The **header** of `Foo` have absoultely no business to include the header of `Bar`. The dependency here is weak and that's exactly what forward declaration provides. Of course, `Bar` needs to be included in the source cpp file whenever the need arises but this has nothing to do with binding the 2 headers together.

Comment: The advantage is that if I include "Bar.h", I will need to include "Foo.h" somehow. If "Bar.h" has not already done this, it may be unclear why I should have to include "Foo.h" myself.

Comment: @PaulDraper There is no advantage whatsoever to include Bar.h in Foo.h unless Foo.h has real need to know the internals of Foo - and in this case it's totally different design. Any SW design book will tell you this. The only "advantage" is covering for laziness of the developer. Such approach can lead to serious flaws. In this piece of code it can be caught early due to compilation failure but in other cases it can cost a lot of sweat and blood.

Comment: @icepack, you are correct. If that is the only reference to Bar in Foo.h, a forward declaration is appropriate.